# Get the value of a global variable inside a function

Tags: python, python-2.7, global-variables

I see many similar questions, but nothing that is exactly the same as my problem, so I have done my research.

I'm trying to access this variable `operatingSystem` from my main file in my function `install`. Now, I know I could pass it with `install(operatingSystem)` but I have 10 other variables like it and I don't want to pass them all.

The variable is defined at the start of the file as `global operatingSystem` then later assigned a string (either `osx`, `win`, or `linux`) when my main file gets the operating system.

However when I try to use `operatingSystem` in my `install` function then it just errors. Do I need to call it as `global operatingSystem` inside my function? Or do I have to do something else?

Comment: How exactly do you *"try to use `operatingSystem`"*? Can you be more specific than *"it just errors"*? Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: `global operatingSystem`, is the way, IMO.

Comment: @pnv `global` is almost never *"the way"*; if you have lots of parameters, consider refactoring into a Parameter Object: http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/introduce-parameter-object

Comment: I meant you can make a global of those variables, something like `global_var_to_be_access_dict` and then access that in desired function.

Comment: @pnv but there is no need to use the `global` keyword in that case.

Comment: Or I didn't get the question, will read the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A global variable can be freely read in a function. To modify it, you need to use the "global" keyword.
[It's all there.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function-other-than-the-one-that-created-them) That is if I understand your question correctly.

```
globvar = 0

def set_globvar_to_one():
    global globvar    # Needed to modify global copy of globvar
    globvar = 1

def print_globvar():
    print globvar     # No need for global declaration to read value of globvar

set_globvar_to_one()
print_globvar()       # Prints 1
```

Comment: Thanks, the `global` declaration in the main file was causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I didnt get actually what you are expecting.Assuming

In `main.py`

```
operatingSystem = "linux"
```

In `yourfile.py`

```
from main import operatingSystem
>>>operatingSystem
"linux"
```

That is no need of `global` here.So

```
install(operatingSystem) #is possible
```